# What are EF Core 2.1 changes in owned types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) last changed at 02/26/2018, but there is some breaking changes that I need to fix.

I have `MyProcessContext` type, used as owned for many entities:

```
public class RequestData
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public MyProcessContext ProcessContext { get; set; }
}

public class MyProcessContext
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class EntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RequestData>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RequestData> builder)
    {
        // all mapped by convention

        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.ProcessContext);

        builder.Property(x => x.Updated).IsRowVersion();

        builder.HasKey(x => x.CorrelationId);
        builder.Property(x => x.CorrelationId).ValueGeneratedNever();
    }
}
```

It works as expected with EF Core 2.0. In debug view I have different entity type for each usage of owned type (`RequestData.ProcessContext#MyProcessContext`):

```
  EntityType: RequestData
    Properties: 
      CorrelationId (Guid) Required PK AfterSave:Throw 0 0 0 -1 -1
        Annotations: 
          Relational:ColumnName: correlation_id      
      Updated (DateTime) Required Concurrency BeforeSave:Ignore AfterSave:Ignore ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate 11 11 -1 -1 0
        Annotations: 
          Relational:ColumnName: updated
    Navigations: 
      ProcessContext (<ProcessContext>k__BackingField, MyProcessContext) ToDependent RequestData.ProcessContext#MyProcessContext 0 -1 1 -1 -1
    Keys: 
      CorrelationId PK
    Annotations: 
      Relational:TableName: process_request
      RelationshipDiscoveryConvention:NavigationCandidates: System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableSortedDictionary`2[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Type]

  EntityType: RequestData.ProcessContext#MyProcessContext
    Properties: 
      RequestDataCorrelationId (no field, Nullable<Guid>) Shadow Required PK FK AfterSave:Throw 0 0 0 0 -1
      ClientId (int) Required 1 1 -1 -1 -1      
    Keys: 
      RequestDataCorrelationId PK
    Foreign keys: 
      RequestData.ProcessContext#MyProcessContext {'RequestDataCorrelationId'} -> RequestData {'CorrelationId'} Unique ToDependent: ProcessContext
    Annotations: 
      Relational:TableName: process_request
      RelationshipDiscoveryConvention:NavigationCandidates: System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableSortedDictionary`2[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Type]
```

After upgrade debug view contains

```
  EntityType: RequestData
      ...
      ProcessContext (<ProcessContext>k__BackingField, MyProcessContext) ToDependent MyProcessContext 0 -1 1 -1 -1
      ...
  EntityType: MyProcessContext
    Properties: 
      RequestDataCorrelationId (no field, Guid) Shadow Required PK FK AfterSave:Throw 0 0 0 0 -1
      ClientId (int) Required 1 1 -1 -1 -1
    Keys: 
      RequestDataCorrelationId PK
    Foreign keys: 
      MyProcessContext {'RequestDataCorrelationId'} -> RequestData {'CorrelationId'} Unique Ownership ToDependent: ProcessContext
    Annotations: 
      Relational:TableName: process_request
      RelationshipDiscoveryConvention:NavigationCandidates: System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableSortedDictionary`2[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Type]
```

Model built like `MyProcessContext` is usual entity. In code like

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                var entityIsOwned = entity.IsOwned();
```

`entityIsOwned` is true, but `entity.DefiningNavigationName` is null now.

I need that name for [custom name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47720357/3009578).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only official change so far (EF Core 2.1) is the addition of the [[Owned] Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#owned-attribute).

However apparently there are breaking changes in the implementation, so `DefiningEntityType` and `DefiningNavigationName` properties are no more reliable (they are not documented anyway - just the "standard" generated useless *"Gets the defining entity type."* and *"Gets the name of the defining navigation."*).

By experiment I've found that they are populated only if the owned type is used in more than one entity. Not sure why they do that, but the main point is that we should not use them, moreover the EF Core code itself also seems to not use them anymore.

From what I saw, `IsOwned`, `DefiningEntityType` and `DefiningNavigationName` terms are determined by the foreign key having `IsOwnership` property equal to `true`.

In other words:

```
var ownershipFk = entityType.GetForeignKeys().FirstOrDefault(fk => fk.IsOwnership);
var isOwned = ownershipFk != null;
var definingEntityType = ownershipFk?.PrincipalEntityType;
var definingNavigationName = ownershipFk?.PrincipalToDependent.Name;
```